# Converting MIDI into CSV in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, csv, midi

for my project I need to convert a MIDI file into CSV for use in a program however I cannot find anywhere any libraries or functions that can do this or allow me to do this. Can anyone point me in the correct direction to something like that?

Also, I found [this](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/midicsv/) program that accomplishes a similar thing, however I cannot figure out how to use as the documentation is not clear. If anyone has any experience using it could they inform me how it works?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a small example of CSV file structure you want to get?

Comment: The main issue was changing midi into text, however the problem has been solved. A silly mistake when I was giving commands. EDIT: If you are curious at all, basically the final result will be in an array suited for input into a NN.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

midiscv [- u - v ] [infile[outfile]]

-u prints how to call information
-v print verbose debugging information

infile should be your midi file

outfile will be your csv file.

thats what i understood from the documentation you posted.. so try that code and see if it works.

Comment: By trying that it returns nothing. [link](http://imgur.com/a/eGIaL)

Comment: Never mind, a mistake in how I was giving commands. Thanks :)